# Eclipse shortcut to format a method call

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any shortcut in Eclipse IDE (Indigo here) to convert from this statement

```
myObject.callMethod(param1, "param2", param3);
```

into this ? :

```
myObject.callMethod(
   param1, 
   "param2", 
   param3
);
```

Comment: You can just select the method and press cntrl+shift+F I guess.l

Comment: Not working in my ide. Perhaps we have to set the formatting rules somewhere else first ? But i'd rather prefer a cool shortcut like ctrl + enter when the cursor is between ( and the first method param.

Comment: Short cut works, but yes you need to setup formatting rules (Window->Preferences->Java->Code style->Formatter). Don't forget it is computer. It does what we say. Without telling what we want, it can't do all on its own.

Comment: Would you mind sharing which part i have to configure in that Formatter section ? It might be just me, but i dont find anything related to formatting method calls.

Comment: You will see example class. In my case I am seeing class Example and method foo, you need to edit this method. To Edit, you need to click on "Edit" right beside profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Shift-F is default combination, you can change one via Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys. Check setting at Java -> Code Style also.

Comment: Hello, do you mind share which part in the Code Style that deals with my original post ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code templates at Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates

Comment: Code Templates ? Are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+F

You can see the setting for the formatting under Window->Preferences->Java->Code style->Formatter

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+Shift+F to format the code.

However in case you want any specific formatting type like spaces instead of tabs then you need to incorporate `code formatter` from Project > Properties > Java Code Style > Formatter. It allows you to define a formatting scheme, export in XML and can be imported on any other machine as well.